# How do I separate workers into pools of jobs with delayed job + heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, delayed-job

My environment is rails 3.1, heroku bamboo stack, delayed_job_active_record, (https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job ) and experimenting with hirefire. (https://github.com/meskyanichi/hirefire) - I can see the delayed_job queue documentation, but how do I apply this on heroku?

I have a max priority set of tasks that get spawned off every hour that I need to dedicate 3 workers to, it takes approx 26 minutes to complete. During that time, less important background tasks need to continue, with perhaps 1 worker dedicated to them.

So I'll set that block of priority tasks to being in a named queue, e.g. 'hourtask', and then name a queue for everything else 'everythingelse' :)

The question is, how do I dedicate heroku workers to specific queues? Is it something to do with the environment variables as per the documentation? It says:

```
# Set the --queue or --queues option to work from a particular queue.
$ RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job --queue=tracking start
$ RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job --queues=mailers,tasks start
```

But I'm not familiar enough with heroku setup to work out how to apply this to my heroku production environment?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's in the README for Delayed Job 3:

DJ 3 introduces Resque-style named queues while still retaining DJ-style priority. The goal is to provide a system for grouping tasks to be worked by separate pools of workers, which may be scaled and controlled individually.

Jobs can be assigned to a queue by setting the queue option:

```
object.delay(:queue => 'tracking').method

Delayed::Job.enqueue job, :queue => 'tracking'

handle_asynchronously :tweet_later, :queue => 'tweets'
```

script/delayed_job can be used to manage a background process which will start working off jobs.

To do so, add gem "daemons" to your Gemfile and make sure you’ve run `rails generate delayed_job`.

You can then do the following:

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job start
$ RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job stop

# Runs two workers in separate processes.
$ RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job -n 2 start
$ RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job stop

# Set the --queue or --queues option to work from a particular queue.
$ RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job --queue=tracking start
$ RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job --queues=mailers,tasks start
```

Work off queues by setting the QUEUE or QUEUES environment variable.

```
QUEUE=tracking rake jobs:work
QUEUES=mailers,tasks rake jobs:work
```

On Heroku, In your procfile, create two entries:

```
worker1: QUEUE=tracking rake jobs:work
worker2: QUEUES=mailers,tasks rake jobs:work
```

and scale them individually:

```
heroku ps:scale worker1=2 worker2=1
```

etc

Comment: My question is if I scale to 4 workers on heroku, how do I set 3 of them to execute off named queue a, and 1 of them to work off named queue b, exclusively.

Comment: "Procfile and the process management commands (heroku run and heroku scale) are only available on the Cedar stack." - I'm on Bamboo, not sure how to configure, but can't use procfile I don't think? http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile

Comment: You need to be on Cedar for this sort of stuff (as is recommended for Rails 3.1 also).

Comment: What do you mean by on heroku in your procfile?  Is that a file in my project?  What's it's path?

Answer (score 1):

Original question asked about HireFire as well.  At this time HireFire does not support named queues [(see HireFire website)](http://hirefireapp.tenderapp.com/discussions/questions/99-support-for-custom-queues) which makes auto-scaling difficult.

Comment: As an update, HireFire _does_ now support named queues. I'm a happy HireFire customer. HireFire howto here: http://hirefire.io/documentation/guides/rails-3-integration