# rails 4 delayed job - Running Delayed Job according to the requested url or domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, delayed-job

I have a requirement in one of the application which deals with the delayed Jobs. I am running two applications using single database.

Here i am facing a problem to call the domain specific delayed Jobs.

For example lets say we are running two applications with domain names abc.com and xyz.com using single database and initiated a delayed job from abc.com and set the time for call a job, as the request from xyz.com is calling milliseconds before the abc.com the job from xyz.com is initiating and job is running with wrong perameters.Here i want a solution by which we can call the delayed job according to the call from the domain or requested url.

Can any one help me in this regard as i was stucked with the possibilities to handle this situations.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set up two different delayed job queues to handle jobs for each domain separately, rather than having all jobs being placed on one single queue.

e.g.

```
object.delay(:queue => 'domain_one').method
object.delay(:queue => 'domain_two').method
```

From here you can then run two separate workers which can service each queue individually.

https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job has information how to use multiple queues with DelayedJob

Comment: Hello David,

Thanks For the answer,Worked fine for me. Actually i am working on Heroku hence i have to scale the workers as shown under this stackoverflow link
"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875653/how-do-i-separate-workers-into-pools-of-jobs-with-delayed-job-heroku"

Thanks once again as your answer lead me to the solution.